# Adding an ordinal field to a MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a *tasks* collection where each task has a unique priority. I'd like to retrieve these tasks from Mongo such that any filtered subset of them will have the relative priorities 0 to *number_of_filtered_objects* -1.

When I sort the filtered tasks (requires a new DB call) by any sortable field the relative priority of the task should not change (assuming the DB contents are unchanged).

My soultion, shown below in Go code, uses the $sort, $group, and $unwind stages to inject the ordinal field into each document.

This is a little inelegant so I'd like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

```
err = collection.Pipe(
    []bson.M{
        {"$match": filter},
        // Start of stages to inject ordinal
        {"$sort": bson.M{"priority": 1}},
        {
            "$group": bson.M{
                "_id":      0,
                "document": bson.M{"$push": "$$ROOT"},
            },
        },
        {
            "$unwind": bson.M{
                "path":              "$document",
                "includeArrayIndex": "relative_priority",
            },
        },
        // Ordinal has now been injected
        {
            "$group": bson.M{
                "_id":               "$document._id",
                "title":             bson.M{"$first": "$document.title"},
                "priority":          bson.M{"$first": "$document.priority"},
                "relative_priority": bson.M{"$first": "$relative_priority"},
            },
        },
        {"$sort": transformSort(sortField, sortOrder)},
        // snipped additional stages to perform pagination
        },
    },
)
```